# ROS Julius error on Kinetic install

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’ve been getting some error about ros-kinetic-julius for a very long time, and wasn’t able to solve it. So I uninstalled ros kinetic and am now trying to re-install it - but the problem is still there. Here is the output, I would appreciate any help!

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
ros-kinetic-jsk-3rdparty : Depends: ros-kinetic-julius but it is not going to be installed
ros-kinetic-julius-ros : Depends: ros-kinetic-julius but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try ‘apt-get -f install’ with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After running: `sudo apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes ros-kinetic-julius`

These were the errors I was getting:

```
----A bunch of logs---
Done
rsync: mkdir "/opt/ros/indigo/share/julius" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674) [Receiver=3.1.1]
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-kinetic-julius_2.1.6-0xenial-20180222-205143- 
0800_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 11
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-kinetic-julius_2.1.6-0xenial-20180222-205143-0800_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So this does seem like something very similar to https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_3rdparty/issues/133.
I'm just new with ROS and need to know how to fix it.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288835/ros-julius-error-on-kinetic-install/) by [ZGee](https://answers.ros.org/users/34674/zgee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-16**:
Welcome! Did you try doing what the output tells you?

```
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’
```

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-04-16**:
For reference this came from: https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-kinetic-julius-error/4484/2

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-04-16**:
@ZGee as I mentioned in the other post. Please add more details for us to be able to help you more. This doesn't have any more information than your original post, and since it doesn't reference my reply others can't leverage the effort that I already spent cross referencing related issues.

**Comment by [ZGee](https://answers.ros.org/users/34674/zgee/) on 2018-04-16**:
@jayess I have run apt-get -f install on each of the packages listed,a and still have errors

**Comment by [ZGee](https://answers.ros.org/users/34674/zgee/) on 2018-04-16**:
@tfoote right sorry, updated the question. Thanks!
Also it seems like I'm having a very similar problem to https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_3rdparty/issues/133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> rsync: mkdir "/opt/ros/indigo/share/julius" failed: No such file or directory (2)
> ```

this seems strange to me: you're installing a Kinetic package and it's looking for `/opt/ros/indigo`. Something is wrong with that package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0